# What contributes to generating guilt?

Tags: succubox

I have an upgrade that requires 10 Quintillion guilt, but I only have under 1000 guilt (I guess I'm a sociopath).

What can I do to generate guilt faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You may have already found this out.]

Once you have secured the world etc. You get to discover and then 'secure' aliens and you get 1 guilt for every 1 trillion aliens discovered, then it will get easier and easier to get guilt with more employees then resulting in 10 Quintillion guilt.

My combination is 3% work, 16% Alien resources, 54% security and 27% Space Exploration. (100%)

p.s getting the 'wormholes' upgrade will help out a lot.